# How to find if a C++ unordered_map has a value 3 (not the key)?

Tags: c++

So I am doing this:

```
if (mp.find(3) == mp.end()) {
    cout << "3 value is there";
```

but it gives right for both when there is a 3 key and/or a 3 value. I just want it to return true when there is a 3 value

Comment: Brute force. You iterate all of the key-value pairs in the container until you find the value as a value or hit the end of the container.

Comment: Side note if you want to check that something is there you should check for `!= end();` (your code does the opposite)

Comment: `find` only searches keys, it will return `end()` iterator if there is no key equal to `3`. It doesn't ever look at values. As user4581301 said, the only way to find a given value in `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` is brute force checking all values.

Comment: This is not how maps work. Maps are always searched by their key value.

Comment: You may want boost:bimap if you want to search from either key or value: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2):

Per the `std::unordered_map` documentation, `find` is looking for a *key* in the map. Fortunately, it's pretty simple to iterate over the pairs in a map to see if a specific *value* is present.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
bool has_value(std::unordered_map<K, V> &map, V val) {
    for (auto &[k, v] : map) {
        if (v == val) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then using that function:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map = {
        {14, 3},
        {56, 2},
        {17, 8}
    };
 
    std::cout << has_value(map, 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This will print `1`.

Comment: [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is provided for this purpose. Edit : any -> any_of

Comment: I'd also note that `std::unordered_map` is not a good choice if the intent is to iterate over it. Iterating involves checking every bucket, most of them empty. If you need to iterate, it's one case where `std::map` may be more desirable.

Comment: Another alternative if by-value look-up is frequent to have a separate `map` or `onordered_map` performing the reverse mapping. If you're only interested in exitance of a value, use a `set` or `unordered_set`. Put both of the containers in a wrapper class that ensures both are kept in synch.

Comment: Or just to use `std::find_if` instead of recreating your own bicycle.